# Setting up a method in go to use a slice of structures

Tags: go

```
//Creating a structure
type Vertex struct {
   X, Y int
}

//Using Add() to add an element to the slice of structure, v
func (v []Vertex) Add() {
   v = append(v, Vertex{2,3})
}

func main() {
   v:= make([]Vertex, 2, 2) //Creating a slice of Vertex struct type
   v.Add()
   fmt.Println(v)
}
```

The go tour site returns the following errors:

> invalid receiver type []Vertex ([]Vertex is not a defined type)

> v.Add undefined (type []Vertex has no field or method Add)

Could someone help me with where exactly is it that I am going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a method, the receiver must be a named type, or a pointer to a named type.

So `func (v []Vertex) Add() { ... }`  isn't valid because `[]Vertex` isn't a named type or a pointer to a named type.

If you wish to use a method on a slice a vertices, you need a new type. For example:

```
type Vertices []Vertex

func (v *Vertices) Add() {
    *v = append(*v, Vertex{2, 3})
}
```

[The whole program will be like this](https://play.golang.org/p/1SmLeK7yTG_S):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y int
}

type Vertices []Vertex

func (v *Vertices) Add() {
    *v = append(*v, Vertex{2, 3})
}

func main() {
    v := make([]Vertex, 2, 2) //Creating a slice of Vertex struct type
    (*Vertices)(&v).Add()
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you Paul. I have one question regarding your code though. I'm still a beginner. What exactly does `(*Vertices)(&v).Add()` do? How does this differ from just using `v := make(Vertices, 2, 2)`? Thanks in advance

Comment: The pattern I chose to use is suitable if you have a slice of Vertex and want to call a method on it. Since `Vertices` is the same underlying type as `[]Vertex`, it's possible to cast the `[]Vertex` into a  `*Vertices` and that's what `(*Vertices)(&v)` is doing. As you observe, you can use the named type directly using `v := make(Vertices, 2, 2)` and then `v.Add()`. That would often be better, depending on your actual use-case of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Creating a structure
type Vertex struct {
   X, Y int
}

type Verices struct{
   Vertices []Vertex
}

func (v *Verices) Add() {
   v.Vertices = append(v.Vertices, Vertex{2,3})
}

func main() {
   v:= Verices{}
   v.Add()
   fmt.Println(v)
}
```

You can't call `Add` on the slice and you can't define a method on that as well, but you can wrap slice in a struct and define methods on top of that.

See in Action:

https://play.golang.org/p/NHPYAdGrGtp

https://play.golang.org/p/nvEQVOQeg7-